# Задать несколько фоновых цветов

Tags: css3, color, css

В css3 можно задать несколько фоновых рисунков. Как задать несколько фоновых ЦВЕТОВ?

Comment: Как это по-вашему должно работать? Вы же всё равно увидите только один фон. Или быть может Вы имеете ввиду градиент?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/blog/dva-fona-i-bolshe

Answer (score 2):

Цвет - штука непрозрачная(альфа канал для цвета до сих пор CSS не понимает. Только для всего фона). Так что ничего нового вы не увидите.
Чтобы создать сочетание цветов, запихните в фон несколько полупрозрачных картинок, либо создавайте нужное сочетание "на лету", суммируя в яваскрипте(или PHP) необходимый массив по определенному правилу. Например:

```
//смешиваем два цвета r,g,b,a и R,G,B,A, где a - альфа канал.

ax = 1 - (1 - a) * (1 - A)
rx = r * a / ax + R * A * (1 - a) / ax
gx = g * a / ax + G * A * (1 - a) / ax
bx = b * a / ax + B * A * (1 - a) / ax
```

Answer (score 0):

Странно пытаться заставить браузер смешивать цвета, когда это можно сделать один раз самому. Но при особом желании можно так:

```css
p {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.5);
  height: 3em;
}

p + p {
  background: rgba(0,0,255,.5);
}

p + p + p {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,0,0,.5), rgba(255,0,0,.5)) rgba(0,0,255,.5); 
}
```

```html
<p><p><p>
```

```css
p {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.5);
  height: 3em;
}

p + p {
  background: rgba(0,0,255,.5);
}

p + p + p {
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,0,0,.5), rgba(255,0,0,.5)),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,255,0,.5), rgba(0,255,0,.5)); 
}
```

```html
<p><p><p>
```